# (MYSQL) Performances in checking if an ID already exists (for ex. in a Poll voters table)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**I would like to know which is the best when I want to check if somebody already participated to a members related event (like a poll)**:

Imagine that I have **a table that stores all the voters votes**. Over time, it can reach a very big size (10000+ entries/votes for 500 different polls).

When I want to check if a member has already voted to my new poll, what's the best? :

1/ Make a **SELECT or a COUNT** on the **"10000+ entries VOTERS table"** to see if said USERID already voted to my new poll.

2/ Having a **TEXT columns in my POLL_main_infos Table** where i **stock/CONCAT the USERIDS** like these:

***"1,15,42,12,523,8521,7444, etc etc."***

And to check, I get that columns as a variable then in my PHP script, I use a REGEX to check if a USERID is already present in it (like looking for ",42,", meaning the USER with the ID "42" already participated to said poll.

Also, **if the second solution is the best, should I stock the IDS in a text column or a BLOB?**

Anyways, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In a Relational Database system it's usually best to store data normalized, so no list of user ids, never.

So using Holmes IV suggested tables it's a simple:

```
SELECT 'User already voted' 
WHERE EXISTS
 (
  SELECT * FROM Participation
   WHERE PollId = 123
     AND UserId = 456
 )
```

With an appropriate index (a UNIQUE index if a user might vote only once per poll) this will be very fast regardless of the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

How much freedom do you have with this? I would say you need 3 tables, 1 for each : Polls, Voters, Participation . In the Polls table you store Poll_ID and Poll_Description. In voter you store all Voter_ID and any other voter information you might have. Then in the participation you store, Poll_ID,Voter_ID, and results or simply a date of when they participated. Then when you want to see such information you query the 3rd table, and join it on the other too for the specifics

The best way to check if a user already voted is to query the Polls_Voters tables in your setup it would be

```
Select *
from Polls_Voters
where Voter_ID = 'ID of voter you are looking for'
and poll_id = 'ID of poll you wish to see if they voted in'
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help. I have full freedom. At the moment i have 3 tables. Let's say 1/Polls (poll_id, poll description), 2/Polls Options, 3/ Polls voters (voter id, vote date, poll id, poll option id). What I wanna know is "what's the best to check if a USER already voted"? Should I search (select, count etc.) on the table (3) or create a TEXT/BLOB columns in Table (1), or even a 4th table with (column 1>"poll_id", column 2> "all_voters_ids_separated_by_commas_stored_in_a_big_text ". Again, thank you for your time.